# Youtube Video Upload in Angular 6 PWA

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, youtube-data-api

I need to upload videos to a specific Youtube channel. I went through the official Javascript docs. But I don't know how to convert those into Typescript. Please share if there is any sample codes for Typescript and Angular. I was trying for the last one week but I couldn't find any solution. I need to use Youtube data API (v3).

Comment: Have you check [this github post (ngx-embed-video)](https://github.com/SamirHodzic/ngx-embed-video)?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 But its for embeding videos not for upload.